# AWS CDK Configuration File With Parameters That Can Be Used In Code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, import, configuration, aws-cdk

I'm using the AWS CDK, and currently I have parameters that I want to be able to change in a sort of configuration file. I can't use the --parameters argument from the command line because A) I need to use the parameter values in the actual code (mainly in function calls/if statements) and B) There are enough parameters that it would be annoying to type every single one into the command line.

Is there some type of way I can just define a JSON or YAML file that the user can edit, and then use those values directly in the cdk_stack.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't exactly need an answer. However, you can create a `.json` file and then simply add a key named `"params"` and the value as a list or whatever you want to name it. There, the user can enter the parameter names, then using the `open()` function and the `json` module you can read the file using python.

Comment: Yeah this seems like the simplest solution, I didn't think the AWS CDK would let me do that honestly but it worked

Answer (score 3):

AWS CDK Context is recommended way to do that:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html